# What is the latest position on 'repositioning splints' for treating TMJ within the medical community?

Tags: dentistry, joints, dental-braces, jaw, tmj-jaw-pain

One of the most popular treatments recommended for TMJ is a removable or fixed splint.

I [have read](https://tmj.org/living-with-tmj/treatments/splints/) that there are four different types of splint, one being a 'Repositioning splint.' This splint is used to move the lower jaw either forward or backward, either to “recapture” a displaced (clicking) disc or to establish a “better” jaw position.

However, I am also reading that these repositioning splints are controversial. According to a [National Institutes of Health brochure on TMJ](https://www.nidcr.nih.gov/sites/default/files/2017-12/tmj-disorders.pdf), “if a splint is recommended, it should be for a short time and should not cause permanent changes in the bite (move jaw forward/back or cover only certain teeth).” It is advised to ask the dentist specifically if the splint he/she is planning for you will change the position of your bite/jaw.

Yet many NHS providers talk about repositioning splints. It is not clear from the material I am reading whether these just mean temporary repositioning, only happening while wearing the splint, or if they will have a more lasting 'repositioning' effect by helping to realign the jaw permanently. What would be the point if a splint only 'establishes a better jaw position' while wearing it, with the jaw returning to rest in the poor position again while not wearing it?

What is the latest position on 'repositioning splints' for treating TMJ within the medical community?